# Remove ? from query string on form post

Tags: php, url-rewriting

I currently have a url like: http://testsite.local/search/?q=findme for my search page once someone makes a query. I use mod_rewrite to rewrite some of the pages and was wondering if it was possible to make this into a nice url like: http://testsite.local/search/1/findme/ (the number 1 being the page of the set of results).

Thanks

Comment: Just a thought: shouldn't it be `/findme/1/` instead of `/1/findme/`?

Comment: Haha yes, yes it should. But thats the least of my problems atm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, none of these methods were what I was looking for, after a little research I just decided to redirect to the correct page when a page has a query string. So when a search was made, I just did this:

```
if ($_GET["posted"] == "true") {<br />
    header("Location: /search/" . $_GET["q"] . "/1/");<br />
}
```

I know the page has just been posted from a form as it has the hidden "posted" field.

Comment: Use [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php), like `urlencode($_GET["q"])`, so strange chars don't cause confusion to your php.

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^search/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ search/?page=$1&q=$2 [L]
```

[Here](http://www.workingwith.me.uk/articles/scripting/mod_rewrite) is a page that has a little info, Google knows much about this too.

You can swap `$1` and `$2` if you want to change the order.

**edit**: If you have something like this in your HTML:

```
<form id="search_form" method="get" action="search">
  <input type="text" name="q" />
  <input type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

With jQuery you can do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#search_form").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    window.location = "/search/1/" + escape($(this).find("input[name=q]").val())
  });
});
```

This will intercept the form submit and do the custom url, and if the user has no javascript, it will still work the old way.

Comment: I have this part sorted already thanks. Like I said above, everything is working perfectly, just the first url after posting the form isn't a nice url, it has the ?q= part in it. I was just looking for a way to change this.

Comment: @luke.browning: I edited my post so it includes an option for what needs to be done in the client side.

Answer (score 1):

Use [parse_url()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) and [parse_str()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php).

```
<?php
$url = 'http://testsite.local/search/?q=findme';
$parsed = parse_url($url);
var_dump($parsed);

parse_str($parsed['query'], $params);
var_dump($params);
```

Output:

```
array
  'scheme' => string 'http' (length=4)
  'host' => string 'testsite.local' (length=14)
  'path' => string '/search/' (length=8)
  'query' => string 'q=findme' (length=8)
array
  'q' => string 'findme' (length=6)
```

Comment: Erm, why? I already have the variables in the url, my problem is making the search form go to http://testsite.local/search/1/findme/ rather than http://testsite.local/search/?q=findme.

Comment: @luke well, your question *was* a bit hazy on what part of the task you need to solve. You'll need what's shown here in combination with some clever JavaScript to insert the value. This is not possible without Javascript

Comment: Oh Ok. I did ask about turning it into a nice url but anyway. I already have the parsing sorted, I have everything working perfectly, just the first url after posting the form isn't a nice url, it has the ?q= part in it. I was just looking for a way to overcome this. I guess I could just post the variables to another page, then construct the nice url but I'd rather not have to go through an extra page.

Answer (score 1):

Use `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /search/

#rewriting only if the request file doesn't exists (you don't want to rewrite request for images or other existing files)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)? index.php?path=$1 [L]
```

After that, you can use the REQUEST_URI in your root index.php file, and can parse the string in it:

```
var_dump($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

or you can use `$_GET['path']`:

Comment: Do it in the main config if you possibly can; .htaccess only if you're stuck on shared hosting somewhere.  See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/howto/htaccess.html#when for more details from Apache.